# Using OpenNLP (tNER) with Hadoop not returning spans

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, opennlp

I am using OpenNLP 1.5.2 with CDH 4 and have an unusual issue.

When I run my jUnit tests, everything passes.
When I run in localJobRunner mode (psuedo or full mode) a lot of the names are not always recognised, and I have 'blank' spans returned, when I was expecting something.

Yes, the names its not finding in local/psuedo/full mode are in my jUnit tests!

Each time I make a call, I pass in a sentence at a time. I tokenise the sentence into a String[] then use these tokens to be found.

an example of what I am calling is:

```
result = Parser.tokenizedNamedEntityRecognition("PK FRESH IGA PLUS LI PORT KENNEDY WA", nameFinder);
assertEquals("IGA", result);
```

Where nameFinder is:

```
InputStream modelIn;         
try {
  modelIn = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "pathToModel" + MRConstants.c_namedEntityRecognitionModelFile);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  fail("fail message here");
}
NameFinderME nameFinder = new NameFinderME(new TokenNameFinderModel(modelIn));
```

in my called method I am doing:

```
String tokens[] = sentence.split(MRConstants.c_singleSpace);
Span nameSpans[] = nameFinder.find(tokens);
```

When invoked via my map method, it doesn't always extract the name. I'd say about 20% fail rate.

An example of one of the many trained sentences is:

```
PK FRESH <START:name> IGA <END> PLUS LI PORT KENNEDY WA
```

I'm not quite sure why, when I call the same method with the same model, it sometimes works when running in local/psuedo/full mode, but always in jUnit.

Any insights would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** I wasn't clearing adaptive data between documents. Silly mistake on my behalf!